# How To Access Variable in Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function `foo` which holds the `bar`. Is it possible to access `bar` from an external function with the code in its current state (ie - not changing anything inside `foo`).

From my understanding, this is not possible as `bar` is only visible for `foo`. My solution would be to create a `get()` that would extract `bar`.

```
var foo = function() {
    var bar = {
        a : 'a',
        b : 'b'
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to access `bar` *without* returning  it.  You'll need to scope it above `foo`:

```
var bar = {
    a : 'a',
    b : 'b'
};
var foo = function() {
  // do stuff with bar
};
```

or have `foo` return `bar`

```
var foo = function() {
    var bar = {
        a : 'a',
        b : 'b'
    };
    return bar;
};
var otherBar = foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

No. `bar` is effectively privately scoped in your above example. If you want to access `bar`, you will have to provide an accessor, like you suggest, e.g. `getBar()`.

Answer (score 1):

bar is a local object only visible from within foo function scope, so you are correct. bar is not accessible from outside unless your foo function returns a function to access it, so your choice to implement a getter sounds about approriate.

Best.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, in its current form, the only way to access the bar variable would be through an accessor method. But depending on how you wish to implement this code, you can declare the bar variable as a property of the foo object.

It would look something like this:

```
var foo = function() {
  this.bar = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b'
  }
}

var baz = new foo();

baz.bar.a; //returns 'a'
```

Answer (score 1):

As others said, you cant, but if all ways count :) ,you can get bar this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var foo = function () {
        var bar = {
            a: 'a',
            b: 'b'
        };
    };

    var haha = function () {
        var evalBar = foo.toString().match("var bar[^}]*};")[0];
        eval(evalBar);
        console.log(bar);
    }

    haha();
</script>
```